# Show tooltip for the selected items in CheckBoxList control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I cannot show more than one checkbox item from CheckboxList control out of 70 items due to space constraints. I should facilitate the user to select multiple items from the CheckboxList control. Hence I want to show Tooltip for the user to make him understand what all items he has selected. After then only user can click on the Insert button to insert into the database. How can I do this in asp.net. Do I need to use JavaScript also? Any suggestions please...

Comment: Can you show relevant parts of the code you already have?

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) do this completely client-side with javascript.

Where do you want to show this tooltip? Tooltips are usually managed by the `title` attribute. Attach an `onchange` event handler to the `<input type="checkbox">`'s and modify the `title` attribute of the element(s) you want to show the tooltip in according to the selection.

Remember [this bug](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-193-onchange-does-not-fire-properly.html) if you're planning to use the `onchange` event handler with checkboxes in IE, and use `onclick` instead.

See a simple example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EwD6m/3/

Comment: I don't know how to get individual checkboxes from the CheckboxList control inside JavaScript. I want tooltips before page posts to server.

I have done the following coding to get the total Checkbox elements into JavaScript.

function CountElems(CheckBoxList1) {
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementById(CheckBoxList1);
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.cells.length; i++) {
 01. How to check if the checkbox is checked
    }
    return false;
}

Now, my doubts are:

01. How to verify whether the checkbox is checked?
02. Atlast how can I show as a tooltip to the end user?